# List all 32 Bit packages on a Gentoo System

Tags: package-management, compiling, gentoo, libraries, 32bit

How can I get a list of all installed 32 Bit packages on a Gentoo Linux system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eix` tool comes to help:

```
eix -I --installed-with-use abi_x86_32
```

- `-I` selects only installed packages
- `--installed-with-use` selects packages with certain USE flag

In this particular case you could even omit `-I`, but I included it just as useful option in general. You may also be interested in the option `-U`, which selects packages which have abi_x86_32, but not necessary were installed with it, and in combination with `-I` it gives yet another list.

If you don't have `eix` on the system yet, just install it with `emerge app-portage/eix`.